# About ngCookies in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to store data in cookies after getting it as per this tutorial:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore.
But I want to know that if values I stored are sent to server as session or not.
I use firefox to see network (F12), and found that cookies value are not sent to server.

Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever values you are storing inside ur $cookieStore will only be on ur local machine .It wont be ever sent to your server untill and unless you will send it manually.
Please give more info so that we can provide you better solution.

Comment: If you have an XSS exploit and you do not have `cookie_httponly` enabled an attacker will be able to steal the cookie(most of the time this will lead to identity theft). Read more on http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-httponly